# Laravel find is returning 2 rows when using find

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following to select my categories:

```
dd(Categories::find($id)->get();
dd($category);
```

But it is selecting 2 rows

[image]

When I use

```
dd(Categories::where('id',$id)->get());
dd($category);
```

it works and returns

[image]

My table stucture

```
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category');
        $table->integer('parent')->nullable();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE categories ADD image LONGBLOB");
```

Comment: Try using this `Categories::find($id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Normally `find()` extract single model by its primary key. The return
>   value is a single model, a collection or null
>
> `get()` extract the  query which you have built

**You are messing up get and  find**

try

```
Categories::find($id)
```

or

```
Categories::where('id','=',$id)->first();
```